# How to query Magento API for newest orders

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, orders, api

I have built a php application which prints shipping labels for orders placed in a magento store - I use the REST API to query for order and customer data.

What is the correct technique to query the Magento store for the set of newest orders only?

So far I have simply been querying for order ids that are greater than the maximum order id that I already have but I think there must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to sort the order results by adding a query string to the request URL containing the order field and the order direction. The field would be "created_at" and the direction "DESC" to get the newest orders first.

The URL would then be:
`http://magentohost/api/rest/orders?order=created_at&dir=DESC`

You should be able to set the amount of results with the query param `limit` (default 10, maximum 100). Then you could try to find new orders until you reach one you already have processed.

Comment: Ok this is a couple of years old but I don't get how this is an accepted answer, the OPs method results in less data coming back and a less complicated script.... Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, it is a few years later, maybe I missed that point. I don't think you can ever do this without recording orders that you have processed by ID. You need some starting point/ending point. Actually both methods are evenly complex. The OP probably already has the best solution, with the difference to my solution that he is querying a field that is indexed in the db (row ID, created_at probably isn't).

Comment: Fair enough! I was thinking that storing the last order ID was the most straightforward thing - I actually found this because I'm about to query a Magneto API myself and I wondered if there was any way of "marking" the seen orders. I was wondering if it's possible to add a custom field to the sales order entity and update it - but I'm not sure if that requires bespoke to the instance. Worst case I'll just take the latest order no.